# SELECT statement using CONCAT() with WHERE using CONCAT()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to build a query in MySQL with this statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(students.FirstName, ' ', students.LastName) AS FullName FROM `students` WHERE CONCAT(students.FirstName, ' ', students.LastName)LIKE '%John%'
```

And now, I use Query Builder from Laravel where I can match the column using `CONCAT()`. Here's my code for reference:

```
    public function getStudent(Request $request)
    {
        $fullName = Student::select(FacadesDB::raw('SELECT CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName) AS FullName'), )
            ->where(FacadesDB::raw('CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName)', 'LIKE', "'% {{ $request->terms }} %'"))
            ->get();
        return response()->json($fullName);
    }
```

When I try to run the code, I got a result like this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName) AS FullName from `students` where CO...' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName) AS FullName from `students` where CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName) is null)

Is there a way that I can achieve this one? It took me like almost 4 hours to solve this code and I still can't solve it. Every help would be appreciated. I'm a new Laravel user, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use map function:-

```
Student::select("firstname","lastname")
->where("firstname","like","%john%")
->orWhere("lastname","like","%john%")
->get()->map(function($query){
    $fullname = $query->firstname." ".$query->lastname
    return ["fullname" => $fullname]
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, dude. This is similar to what I solved lately. I'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and just phrase your query as:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName
FROM students
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%John%' OR LastName LIKE '%John%';
```

Updated Laravel code:

```php
public function getStudent(Request $request)
{
    $fullName = Student::select(FacadesDB::raw('CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName) AS FullName'), )
        ->where(FirstName, 'LIKE', '%John%')
        ->orWhere(LastName, 'LIKE', '%John%')
        ->get();
    return response()->json($fullName);
}
```

Comment: I still have an error like this:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SELECT CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName)' in 'field list'`

Comment: Try removing `SELECT` from the input to the raw function.

Comment: I remove `SELECT` and still got this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CONCAT(LastName, ", ", FirstName)' in 'field list'`

Comment: Check the docs for making a raw query.  The SQL query I gave you at the top of my answer should work fine.